# memory layout - C union

Tags: c, memory

I have a union type of array of three integers (4 bytes each), a float (4 bytes), a double (8 bytes) and a character (1 byte).

if I assign 0x31313131 to each of the three integer elements and then printed the union's character, I will get the number 1. Why ?

I don't understand the output I know that the bits of 3 0x31313131 is
001100010011000100110001001100010011000100110001001100010011000100110001001100010011000100110001

Comment: Cause you're lucky.  Demons could have flown out of your nose.

Comment: You are very familiar with your code, but we are not. Please post the code, and plese tell us what compiler and platform (OS+processor)

Comment: @cHao: Based on the description, there's probably no undefined behavior.  Writing one element of a union and reading another reinterprets the bits as a representation of the appropriate type.  (I think it was undefined in some earlier versions of C.)

Comment: @Keith: It's still undefined, AFAIK.  Anything can happen, even its appearing to work.

Comment: @cHao: A footnote in N1570, the latest draft of the C11 standard, section 6.5.2.3, says: "If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’).  This might be a trap representation."  C99 has the same footnote.  The C90 standard (in section 6.3.2.3) explicitly says the behavior is implementation-defined, not undefined.

Comment: We always wondered whether an implementation was allowed to implementation-define the behavior as undefined... :-)

Comment: @KeithThompson It is unspecified behavior. First of all, foot notes of ISO standards are not normative. The relevant section of the standard is ISO 9899:2011 6.2.6.1 "7  When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object
representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values." (continued-->)

Comment: "8  Where an operator is applied to a value that has more than one object representation, which object representation is used shall not affect the value of the result. Where a value is stored in an object using a type that has more than one object representation for that value, it is unspecified which representation is used, but a trap representation shall not be generated."

Comment: Footnotes aren't normative, but they clarify the intent. If a footnote is inconsistent with the normative text, that's a bug in the standard. *"... the bytes of the object representation ...  take unspecified values"*.  That's not directly relevant to this case.  A value was stored to the `int[3]` member, which is 12 bytes; only 1 byte was read, and that's one of the 12 that was stored.

Comment: *"Where a value is stored in an object using a type that has more than one object representation for that value, it is unspecified which representation is used, but a trap representation shall not be generated."*  Also not directly relevant.  It refers to cases where a type has multiple representations for the same value, such as `+0` vs. `-0` (though I think there are special rules for that), or pointers consisting of a base and an offset where different combinations might point to the same memory location.  In addition, there are special rules for treating arbitrary objects as byte arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because '1' == 0x31. You are printing it as character, not integer.

since it is a union all the int and char share the same memory location (the float and double does not matter in this context).  So assigning 0x31313131 to the int **does** affect the char value -- nothing much confusing there.

Comment: Indeed; check out the evidence: http://www.asciitable.com/ — the original author possibly wanted to `printf` with a formatter like `%02x`?

Comment: Thanks, but i thought the layout in the memory will be like that 96 bits for the array. then 32 bits for the float, 64 bits for double and 8 bits for the char. the array only occupy 96 bits.

Comment: @nullException, see Soren's edit: it is union - so all fields share the same 96 bytes.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOH thanks,, I got it now! and the machine is little endian, this is why it's reading the last 4 bits.

Comment: @nullException: No, it's not reading the last 4 bits, it's reading the *first* 8 bits.  (Endianness affects whether the *first* 8 bits are the high-order or low-order bits, but since you stored `0x31313131`, you'll get the same result either way.)  All members of a union start at the same memory location (offset 0 of the union object); they may have different sizes.  And again, it would be easier to discuss this if you'd post actual code rather than describing it.

Answer (score 1):

Every member of a union has the same starting address; different members may have different sizes.  The size of the union as a whole is *at least* the maximum size of any member; there may be extra padding at the end for alignment requirements.

You store the value `0x31313131` in the first three `int`-sized memory areas of your union object.  `0x31313131` is 4 bytes, each of which has the value `0x31`.

You then read the *first* byte (from offset 0) by accessing the character member.  That byte has the value `0x31`, which happens to be the encoding for the character `'1'` in ASCII and similar character sets.  (If you ran your program on an EBCDIC-based system, you'd see different results.)

Since you haven't shown us any actual source code, I will, based on your description:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void hex_dump(char *name, void *base, size_t size) {
    unsigned char *arr = base;
    char c = ' ';

    printf("%-8s : ", name);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        printf("%02x", arr[i]);
        if (i < size - 1) {
            putchar(' ');
        }
        else {
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    union u {
        int arr[3];
        float f;
        double d;
        char c;
    };

    union u obj;

    memset(&obj, 0xff, sizeof obj);

    obj.arr[0] = 0x31323334;
    obj.arr[1] = 0x35363738;
    obj.arr[2] = 0x393a3b3c;

    hex_dump("obj",     &obj,     sizeof obj);
    hex_dump("obj.arr", &obj.arr, sizeof obj.arr);
    hex_dump("obj.f",   &obj.f,   sizeof obj.f);
    hex_dump("obj.d",   &obj.d,   sizeof obj.d);
    hex_dump("obj.c",   &obj.c,   sizeof obj.c);

    printf("obj.c = %d = 0x%x = '%c'\n",
           (int)obj.c, (unsigned)obj.c, obj.c);

    return 0;
}
```

The `hex_dump` function dumps the raw representation of any object, regardless of its type, by showing the value of each byte in hexadecimal.

I first fill the union object with `0xff` bytes.  Then, as you describe, I initialize each element of the `int[3]` member `arr` -- but to show more clearly what's going on, I use different values for each byte.

The output I get on one system (which happens to be little-endian) is:

```
obj      : 34 33 32 31 38 37 36 35 3c 3b 3a 39 ff ff ff ff
obj.arr  : 34 33 32 31 38 37 36 35 3c 3b 3a 39
obj.f    : 34 33 32 31
obj.d    : 34 33 32 31 38 37 36 35
obj.c    : 34
obj.c = 52 = 0x34 = '4'
```

As you can see, the initial bytes of each member are consistent with each other, because they're stored in the same place.  The trailing `ff` bytes are unaffected by assigning values to `arr` (this is not the only valid behavior; the standard says they take unspecified values).  Because the system is little-endian, the high-order byte of each `int` value is stored at the lowest position in memory.

The output on a big-endian system is:

```
obj      : 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c ff ff ff ff
obj.arr  : 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c
obj.f    : 31 32 33 34
obj.d    : 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
obj.c    : 31
obj.c = 49 = 0x31 = '1'
```

As you can see, the high-order byte of each `int` is at the lowest position in memory.

In all cases, the value of `obj.c` is the *first* byte of `obj.arr[0]` -- which will be either the high-order or the low-order byte, depending on endianness.

There are a *lot* of ways this can vary across different systems.  The sizes of `int`, `float`, and `double` can vary.  The way floating-point numbers are represented can vary (though this example doesn't show that).  Even the number of bits in a byte can vary; it's at least 8, but it can be bigger.  (It's exactly 8 on any system you're likely to encounter).  And the standard allows *padding bits* in integer representations; there are none in the examples I've shown.